# SSIS 2005 to 2019

Tags: ssis

In the company where I work I have SSRS, SSIS and SSAS projects done in 2005 and 2008, and at this moment the company has purchased VS 2019, is it possible to migrate ssis packages from 2005 and 2008 to 2019 directly? I can't find anything on the net that is very specific in relation to this matter.

Thank you

greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is the answer.

If the packages were built using only standard, out of the box, tasks and components and there's no scripting involved, you can run that 2005 package with the 2019 execution engine and it'll work.

Behind the scenes, the run-time engine will create an in-memory copy of the old package and upgrade to 2019 and then run it (and then dispose of it).

When you open the package in the VS designer, then that transient upgrade becomes permanent.

With the 2016 release of the VS designer tools, MS gave us "multi-targeting" for SSIS package development. Prior to that, you needed VS 2005 to create SQL Server 2005 packages. VS 2008 or 2010 for SQL Server 2008/2008R2. VS 2012 for SQL Server 2012, etc. With 2016 though, you could now go into the project properties and specify "target 2012, 2014, 2016" etc for deployment. This continues with 2019.

Also new for 2012 is the concept of a Project deployment model. The old stuff is under the Package deployment model. It's still a valid approach and you'll likely want to remain in that model as there are differences for configuration, logging, package execute package task between them.

Script Task/Components are tricky. Some times they upgrade easy. Others you merely need to open the Task/Component and click recompile and errors sort themselves out. If someone got really clever with metadata and pipelines in a Script Component, then you're likely looking at a rewrite. The default language has switched between 2005/2008 which only offered VB.NET to C#. Both compile to IL so it doesn't matter but most folks stick with the default.

If you used custom components, then you'll need to acquire new versions built on the target set of SSIS binaries (and pray they haven't gone out of business). Register in GAC etc

You specify you purchased VS 2019, but do you have a SQL Server 2019 license to go with that? Otherwise, you're pouring new wine into old skins

Comment: I've VS 2019 and SQL Server 2017

Comment: 2017 is "new enough" Just be sure you change the SSIS project targeting to be 2017. The default will be 2019

Comment: Thank you for that, i didn't know that.